# What is the meaning of $\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, poynting-vector

Consider that for a single $\mathbb{R}^3$ point-source emitter of RF, the $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ fields (when treated as transverse sinusoids and ignoring interference properties) are always perpendicular. What would their cross product ($ \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B} $) represent? I've seen things calling it "Drift", but that always involves other [non-constant] terms. I'm interested in this quantity and what, if anything, it means or does in nature.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector

Comment: My understanding of E-and-B-fields being perpendicular come from my thinking about the two fields being radiated by a point-source in R^3 as propagated transverse waves. Thus, at every point, u, E(u) perp B(u).

Comment: You should note that even for point sources, the electric and magnetic fields are only approximately orthogonal. And it should be clear that one can cook up all sorts of weird situations where they are definitely not orthogonal by superposing plane waves in different directions.

Comment: they are perpendicular in vacuum.

Comment: @Phoenix87 That's pretty much incorrect. They're perpendicular in vacuum for a plane wave, which is much more restricted.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'm way over-simplifying this, I'm supposing a single point-source radiating RF, and considering this RF as two orthogonal sinusoids.

Comment: Then you're in "way over-simplified EM", not "standard EM".

Comment: @nick5435 Please edit the post to reflect what you said in your previous comment. It's really confusing as written because the post states something which is false and asks for further information based on that false premise.

Comment: Steady on chaps. It seems obvious what Nick is thinking about and to prove it Emilio's answer is a masterpiece of clarity and concision. I sometimes wonder if the time spent making comments wouldn't be better spent writing answers.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have done as such. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's better but it's still not quite correct. The $\mathbf E·\mathbf B=0$ property only holds asymptotically, for the radiative component (which goes down as $1/r^2$). However, there are always other terms which make $\mathbf E·\mathbf B\approx 0$ only ever be approximate. Tricky (and not crucial), but if you want your details to be right, then you still have a bit more fixing to do.

Comment: @JohnRennie It wasn't at all obvious from the original post. Phoenix87's answer is even more concise.

Comment: The $\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}$ drift to which you refer is not from Poynting's theorem.  It results if one makes certain assumptions for Ohm's law (e.g., $\mathbf{E}$ = $- \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}$) and is often used in MHD.  The relation between $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ only holds if the medium is assumed to be infinitely conducting.  However, if there is an $\mathbf{E}$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{B}$ and its time variation occurs slower than the gyroperiod of a particle, then you can still get $\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}$ drifts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modulo constants, this cross product is called the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector),
$$
\mathbf S=\frac1{\mu_0}\mathbf E\times\mathbf B.
$$
It represents the flow of energy in the electromagnetic field, so that the energy density $u=\tfrac12\varepsilon_0\mathbf E^2+\tfrac1{2\mu_0}\mathbf B^2$ obeys, in free space, the continuity equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\nabla·\mathbf S=0.
$$
In the presence of charges, this conservation law acquires a source term equal to the work per unit volume performed by the charges on the field. This fact is known as [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem).

In addition, the Poynting vector is proportional to the momentum density of the electromagnetic field,
$$
\mathbf g=\frac1{c^2}\mathbf S=\varepsilon_0\mathbf E\times\mathbf B.
$$
This is subject to a similar conservation law as the energy density, except that now the flow term is a tensor quantity (which it must, being the flow of a vector quantity) known as the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).

Comment: Just to add that in some situations it is not the flow of energy $-$ for example, constant and perpendicular $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ won't show the real direction of the energy flow. Nevertheless, I am not sure whether this holds when interpreted relativistically.

Comment: Constant and perpendicular fields will yield, once you take the full problem into account (including sources and a finite spatial extent) closed loops of energy moving around the place in circles. Some people are bothered by this but it is a perfectly consistent energy flow. Whether there are other similar vectors that avoid that behaviour is still an open question.